# How can I get a renamed $(Platform) in MSbuid?

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a solution that contains a few renamed Platform. By default, they are "Any Cpu" "x86" or "x64" but you are allowed to modify the platform name.
Let's say I have a renamed platform "MyPlatform1".Then I can do `MSBuild myApp.sln -p:Platform=MyPlatform1` to build. However, the `$(Platform)` that I specified in my .csproj  `Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'MyPlatform1' "` always gives `x86`.

How can I get the customized platform name in my msbuild task?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="ERROR.cs" Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'MyPlatform1' " />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Maybe something wrong in your xx.csproj causes this issue, share the content of xx.csproj if possible?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I have updated it. I just want to remove Error.cs from compilation for MyPlatform1. The `$(Platform)` is always `x64` if you `<Message Text="$(Platform)" />`

Comment: There is no reason what-so-ever to add the xml element `<Platforms>` in your above example.

Comment: @CJohnson It is created by the project by default. I tried to remove it but still the same. Command-line should pass the `Platform` as a global variable like `configuration` . But it is overridden by `x64` before build.

Comment: @CJohnson fyi VS moved to `Configurations` and `Platforms` properties to populate the dropdown menus for available configurations, with defaults being defined in the SDK. Previously it would textually parse `'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='...'` in the project fils which works as long as you don't manually touch it (non-goal for .NET Core)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using command like `msbuild xx.sln` instead of `msbuild xx.csproj`. And this will make a big difference.

You should figure out the difference between `Solution Platform` and `Project Platform`. In vs, right-click solution and choose `Configuration Manager`, you can see something like:

[image]

When I use command: `msbuild xx.sln -p:Platform=TestPlatform`, since this solution only has a ConsoleApp1 project, it now actually represents command `msbuild ConsoleApp1.csproj -p:Platform=AnyCpu` . I think you have a similar situation like this.

**Update:**
Maybe you can define a custom property in xx.csproj like this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64;x86</Platforms>
    <RemoveOrNot>false</RemoveOrNot>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="ERROR.cs" Condition=" '$(RemoveOrNot)' == 'true' " />
  </ItemGroup>
```

It works for commands like `msbuild xx.sln -RemoveOrNot= true` or `msbuild xx.csproj -RemoveOrNot= true`.

Comment: I'm using msbuild `xxx.sln` and is there any way to let the `TestPlatform` pass into the `.csproj`? Apparently `$(Configuration)` can receive `msbuild xxx.sln -p:Configuration=MyConfiguration` correctly. But not `$(Platform)`.

Comment: Do you have any special reason that you have to use something like $(Platform) property? I mean it's quite easy to define a custom property to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, since the CI environment is set and I simply cannot change the MSbuild command they invoke the build. I can only modify the project or sln file. So the question is : How can I make a condition based on the /p:Platform  passed in from command line.

Comment: See my first pic in my answer,you can click the Solution Platform to create new platform for the solution, but when you click the project Platform , you can only see edit, no New button. So no matter how many solution platforms you create, when you use command like `msbuild xx.sln -p:Platform= (no matter what)`,  the value passed to project will always be one of `anycpu, x86 or x64`.   Unless you use command like `msbuild xx.csproj`, but it's not you want.

Comment: I got your point. Maybe it's not `$(Platform)`. I just want to get the `/p:Platform` that passed in from `msbuild myapp.sln -p:Platform=xxx`. Is it possible or any workaround?

Comment: @joe In my opinion, it's impossible. Cause if you open the xx.sln file with notepad you'll see the definitions there. You can see something like MyPlatform1.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64, MyPlatform1.Build.0 = Debug|x64, that means if xx.sln get passed parameter MyPlatform1, then it will pass Debug|x64 to project. And this is can't be avoided, or you'll break the build process. -------------

Comment: But, though I think $(Platform) is not recommended and can't work, why not consider using $(Configuration)!  The system don't support new **project ** platform, but it supports new **project** configuration. So I think $(Configuration) is something you can consider.

Comment: The reason that I don't consider $(Configuration) is that I have no control of the build command, it is supervised in the cloud by someone else, even though I want to, I can only modify source file including .csproj and .sln. And that's why I asked this question. And I think it might be possible since from build logs `ValidateSolutionConfiguration` clearly indicates my renamed platform. And there is a PlatformMapping happens before projects get built. see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/assignprojectconfiguration-task?view=vs-2019)

Comment: And you are absolutely right. However, the target solution was considered as "support multiple toolbox platform" such that they selected the projects to build by using `platform`. This isn't right, but it's already there and I can't change it.